# Why does my try/catch reprint the elements of my array?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a while loop within a try statement, and have it set up to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. I then catch the error, and have it print something plus the previous element in the array (`newArray[i-1]`). However it seems rather than print the previous element, the entire loop is run again from `i=0` and the entire contents of the array are printed twice.

I tried to move the while loop outside of the try statement and have the code `try` to print to the console rather than trying the entire loop.

```java
try {
    while(i <= newArray.length) {
        System.out.println(newArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Arrays Out of Bounds, going back to previous element: " + newArray[i-1]);
}
```

Like I said I want to print just the previous element however the entire contents of the array are printed. Can someone explain why and how I can achieve the result I'm actually looking for?

Comment: Can you try to add the code which you tried, when u moved the code outside the try block? Because I'm not able to completely understand the line "I tried to move the while loop outside of the try statement and have the code try to print to the console rather than trying the entire loop."

Comment: @fiendishbrokeboi From the code you posted there seems to be no problem, it does what you want. Share more code please.

Comment: Just before we get too far, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException`, aka a developer error. This is an exception arising most often because a programmer made a mistake in how they utilized some piece of code (no bounds checks); _catching_ these exceptions isn't fixing them, it's ignoring the mistake.

Comment: Please share the code that had the problem. This piece of code does not have any problem.

Comment: Should be: `while(i < newArray.length) {` not `while(i <= newArray.length) {`. There is no array index at `newArray.length`. Remember... array indexing is zero (0) based.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the program and as you guys said now its working like a charm:

```
class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] newArray = {"Volvo","BMW","Ford","Mazda"};
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Printing newArray: ");
        while(i <= newArray.length) {
            try {
                System.out.println(newArray[i]);
            }   catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught Runtime Error, ArrayOutOfBoundsException please fix. Printing newArray[i-1]: " + newArray[i-1]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }



}
```

I had already deleted the previous code to move on to a new project so I don't remember what it looked like or what I could have changed to make it print correctly so I'm going to go ahead and consider this question answered. Thank you people.